# GldatePicker is not showing calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
<td>
    <ul class="input-list style-1 clearfix">
        <li>
            <input id="req_date" type="text" />
                                    @*
            <div gldp-el="mydate" style="width:320px; height:200px; position:absolute;top:30px;left:0px;z-index:1000;"></div>*@

        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
$('#req_date').glDatePicker();

$('.editimg').click(function () {
    var row_num = parseInt($(this).parent().index()) + 1;
    var parentcrimsId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var childcrimsId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/Editcrims',
        //   data: JSON.stringify(SearchDetails),
data: { Cr_ParentId: parentcrimsId.trim(), Cr_childId:childcrimsId.trim() },
        // contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //   processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

            $.each(data, function (index) {
$('#req_date').val(data[index].Requested_Date);
},
     error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Herewith i have added my code not able to get the datepicker, 
When i trying to assign a date value to input text control on edit via ajax method. Datepicker calendar is not showing.  please assist me. i have tried for bootstrap also same kind of problem when i assign the date value to control.

On Editing i need to show the date from database then if any changes required we need to select and modify the date from datecontrol.

I Have added my faulty code in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/44cce57j/2/

Comment: Is your _glDatePicker()_ caled in a _$(document).ready()_ (or equivalent) ?

Comment: when i  called inside $(document).ready() it is not working, instead of tht inside the $(document).read(){     $(window).load(function () {

            $('#req_date').glDatePicker(
     {
         showAlways: true
     });
           });});

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ while assign the date value to the control, my datepicker not showing the calendar, can u assist.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the faulty code on JSFiddle, please ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ https://jsfiddle.net/44cce57j/2/

Comment: First of all, you included the JS file twice. Then, where's the code to initializes the datepickers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I tested (derivated from the basic example of the library) and it worked with *$(document).ready()*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="glDatePicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#example').glDatePicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @AdreNaLiNe-DJ, there is some jquery script version problem, My layout page has some script due to that reference my current page has some problem in calendar control thanks for your help.